# Django DictReader change " " values in name[""] == " " in None

Tags: python, django, csv, upload

I want to replace from all 40 columns the null data from an uploaded csv file.

Can i loop trough all columnnames in one and replace the " " with none 
at the moment i have:

```
f = io.TextIOWrapper(form.cleaned_data['data_file'].file, encoding='utf-8')
f.readline()

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for item in reader:
    if(item['columnname'] == ''):
           item['columnname'] = None
```

but i dont want to do that for 40 column names.. 
But is this possible?

Can i loop trough all columnnames in one and replace the " " with none 
at the moment i have:

```
f = io.TextIOWrapper(form.cleaned_data['data_file'].file, encoding='utf-8')
            f.readline()
f.readline()
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for item in reader:
                if item == '':
                    item = None

                if(item['columnname'] == ''):
                    item['columnname'] = None
```